# time zone difference from google sheet to calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I have this piece of code that reads from spreadsheet cells task name and a date and schedule a full day calendar event with task name on that date.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function AddToCalendar1(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process - 2 exempts my header row
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();   // Number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1, numColumns); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var complete = "Yes";

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var eventDate = row[0]; //date to schedule
    var task = row[1];  //job description 
    var status = row[2] // Scheduled?

    if (status != complete) {
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3);

      var c =CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();     

      var event = c.createAllDayEvent(task, new Date(eventDate));

      Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());

      currentCell.setValue(complete);
    }

  }

}
```

the issue is at this moment it is 11:10 PM GMT-3, now(not sure if it matters)
The cell has the value `'2019-09-09'`
but `'eventDate'` is `'Sun Sep 08 2019 23:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'`

So the task is scheduled the day before.

How can I change this?

Calendar and spreadsheet has the same timezone configuration which is GMT-3

should/can I change the timezone the script is executing?

***EDIT***
I just found adding a few hours I can get this done, but it does not look like the right solution

```
   var event = c.createAllDayEvent(task, new Date(eventDate.getTime()+3600000*10));
```

***Edit2***

this is the result of running the test function

```
[19-09-10 13:44:06:319 ART] Sheet time zone: America/Los_Angeles
[19-09-10 13:44:06:320 ART] Script time zone: America/New_York
[19-09-10 13:44:06:414 ART] Date from sheet: Thu Oct 10 2019 03:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Also, not sure what change now I have an error on this line

```
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(task, new Date(eventDate.getTime()+3600000*10));
```

> ```
> Cannot find function getTime in object .
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend double checking the time zone set for both the sheet and the script.

*I see the behavior you're describing when there's a timezone mismatch between the two.*

I setup a sheet which has the value `2019-09-09` in cell A1. Then I setup a container-bound script with the following function:

```
function testTimeZones() {
  Logger.log('Sheet time zone: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log('Script time zone: ' + Session.getScriptTimeZone());
  Logger.log('Date from sheet: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).getValue());
}
```

When both the sheet and the script have their time zones set to `(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires`, this is the logging output after executing that function:

```
[19-09-09 22:28:26:039 PDT] Sheet time zone: America/Buenos_Aires
[19-09-09 22:28:26:041 PDT] Script time zone: America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
[19-09-09 22:28:26:127 PDT] Date from sheet: Mon Sep 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (ART)
```

However, when I switch to script time zone to `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time`, this is the logging output:

```
[19-09-09 22:37:34:116 PDT] Sheet time zone: America/Buenos_Aires
[19-09-09 22:37:34:118 PDT] Script time zone: America/New_York
[19-09-09 22:37:34:207 PDT] Date from sheet: Sun Sep 08 2019 23:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Which matches the behavior you're seeing.

Two things to try:

1. Verify the script time zone by checking `File` -> `Project Properties` in the Script Editor.
2. If 1 doesn't work, as a sanity check, try executing the test function above in your project. Either alter it to point to a cell with a date value, or use it as is by creating a temporary sheet with a date in cell A1. Consider updating the question with the results to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Thanks, one comment on this "Verify the script time zone by checking File -> Project Properties in the Script Editor." It is a read-only property set to GMT -5.

Comment: It helps to be *very specific*, as not all time zones behave the same. For example, `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time` changes depending on time of year due to [daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), hence the `(EDT)` (Eastern Daylight Time) in the date object output.

In regards to the script time zone property, are you the script owner? In the example script I created, I'm able to change the property.

Comment: `Zona horaria (GMT-05:00) Hora del Este` And see last edit with results from the test function

Comment: Regarding the `Cannot find function...` error... if you created a new sheet to run the test function, you have a new "active" sheet which does not contain data in the locations that your code expects. So no cell value is retrieved, no date object instantiated, etc.

Comment: In your question, you stated, "Calendar and spreadsheet has the same timezone configuration which is GMT-3". Unfortunately, this isn't true and this is the root cause of the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: It turns out that I ask the owner to change the scripting time zone and it worked. It was true that Calendar and Spreadsheet have the same timezone, the difference was in scripting. Did you expect to be scripting and spreadsheet the same timezone by default? . Or maybe I expressed myself in a wrong way, I'm pretty new into scripting. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, when I copy/pasted from your post in the comment above, I misinterpreted it. I was thinking "script and sheet" instead of "calendar and sheet" (mostly because there wasn't a calandar directly involved in the interaction being discussed). You expressed yourself just fine.